# element "I" undefined [XHTML 1.0 Tranditional]

Tags: html

```
<div id="vid3">
    <a href="../Videos/motionTween.html">
        <img src="../images/vid3.fw.png" width="200" height="111" align="left" margin-right="10" alt="vid3" />
    </a>
    <h3 style="margin-top:-5px; margin-bottom:-15px">
        <a href="../Videos/motionTween.html"> Flash Tutorial: How to Motion Tween</a>
    </h3>
    <p>
        by <I>Moynzy</I> <br />
        In this simply and easy tutorial you will learn how to move an object from the left side of the screen to the right side of the screen.
    </p>                  
</div>
```

Hello, i get validtion error, I have closed of my I tag. What's the big whole idea guys?

Comment: Uppercase `<I>` is valid in HTML (it's case insensitive) but not in XHTML. Your `DOCTYPE` is XHTML. Just change that tag to to lower case (`<I>Moynzy</I>` to `<i>Moynzy</i>`).

Comment: @Adriano that comment should be an answer.

Comment: @IanRoberts yes maybe but I was pretty lazy to write it down as a decent answer!

Comment: It was a very good answer. Fixed my problem

Comment: @Adriano, turning a good comment to an answer would help people, as they will see that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Ok, I guess you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the error I assume you have `DOCTYPE` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

You declared your document to be XHTML and error is because `<I>` tag (uppercase) is valid in HTML (because HTML tags and attribute names are case insensitive) but it's not valid in XHTML (because it's case sensitive and tag must be lowercase `<i>`, see [XHTML 1.0 specifications § 4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2)).

To fix it just change this:

```
by <I>Moynzy</I> <br />
```

To this:

```
by <i>Moynzy</i> <br />
```